# Linux: how to resolve symbol from specific library

Tags: linux, shared, symbols

I am working with a system that has a bunch of shared libraries, some of which link to the system-installed OpenSSL. One library has a company requirement that it use a specific hardened and approved version of OpenSSL. When I run the program, there is a chance that the vanilla system OpenSSL is loaded before the hardened one, and this causes the special library to use the symbols from that one.

Is there a way when linking the code to demand that a symbol be only resolved from a specific library? Note: I don't mean using dlopen/dlsym, I mean instructing the loader to disregard symbols from a particular library. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "When I run the program, there is a chance that the vanilla system OpenSSL is loaded"? Loader doesn't work at random - the loading order is predefined and you can check with `ldd` which libraries get loaded.

Comment: Sorry - to clarify, the program is itself a loadable module as part of a bigger system and there is no guarantee exactly when it will be loaded.

Comment: Still - you can check with `ldd` which libraries the module depends on. What's the "chance"? Some minimal examples would be great if you can produce it.